# Archimesh License

Tags: objects, add-on, archimesh-add-on

I'm trying to understand what exactly I can do with archimesh. I have already researched the license is GPL, but when I read about it, it gets really confusing.

For example, if I make a kitchen in object format (or any other format that is not blender) using archimesh, am I allowed to sell this file? Or does it have to be put up there for free since the add-on is free?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an addon and not about Blender. Questions and support for addons should be addressed to the creator of the addon in question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. Questions about licences and legal themes are considered off topic. Please read: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/422/are-licensing-questions-off-topic

Comment: @VRM There is no issue asking about add-ons, the issue is that this is a licensing question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the right forum for this question, but I think I have a satisfactory answer anyway.

(All sensible declarations about "I'm not an attorney," go here).

The GPL license allows the covered software (in this case, Archimesh, but this also applies to Blender) to be used for all purposes, including commercial purposes. [Documented here.](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#CanIUseGPLToolsForNF)

The only requirements are on the distribution of the software itself and software that uses or is derived from the original software covered by the GPL license. In these cases, you basically have to also offer your customers the original software under the GPL license.

Content produced USING the software is neither covered by, or restricted by the GPL license, but must be controlled by the original content owner (you). To wit, you can distribute your own original content (such as a kitchen created using Archimesh) under any license you please. Furthermore, you can even sell the Archimesh addon as-is (or with modification), *BUT* you must also show the people who buy that addon where to get the original Archimesh for free.

EDIT: It's worth noting that although you have to tell customers where to get Archimesh for free, this is only if you're selling Archimesh or a derivative piece of software. This does not apply to models/scenes/images that you make using Archimesh.